# Looping through cells within multiple tables and changing value if font color =

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has 3-6 tables in it. I need to use a macro that will change a value from say "30" to "'30" if any of the cells within the row are red. This is because red rows are cancelled reservations; we still need the value and I don't want my other formulas to count that number as a valid number (since it's not an actual reservation.) I've perused many articles with options but usually these articles have a range that is set with a specific table name. Since there are multiple tables, the tables change and I don't know how to make it dynamic. Furthermore, I don't want to have to update the macro each time. If I can circumvent naming the particular tables, my code could work on each sheet (sheets change monthly). One of the issues with my code is that the value I need to change is always in column J. My current code, I imagine, would see the whole row as needing to be changed. I currently get a Run-time error 6: Overflow.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughAllTablesInWorksheet()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim Cell As Range
Dim OldValue As Integer

For Each tbl In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

        For Each Cell In tbl.DataBodyRange
            If Cell.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                OldValue = Cell.Value
                Cell.Value = "'" & OldValue
            End If
        Next Cell

Next tbl

End Sub
```

I used the following to help me get where I am: http://www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work by changing the line "For Each Cell In tbl.DataBodyRange" to "For Each Cell In tbl.ListColumns(10).Range".